# Passing token from an httpwebrequest in silverlight toward MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, security, httpwebrequest

I have a silverlight application calling an asp.net mvc 3 website (using as webservices application) by using httpwebrequest.
i would like to add basic security : send a token representing a guid of an user.

- how to send the token, must i use credentials attribute ? (seems adding header is not available in silverlight application)

  - how to retrieve the token (or credentials) in MVC controller ?

thanks by advance